# AngularJS dynamically assign IDs to elements in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way in AngularJS that I can dynamically ID  or  in a dynamic table? I have this table that dynamically adds rows.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameBlue}}</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">Round</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">{{nameRed}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="tablerows">
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in tableArray track by $index">
                          <td>Red Corner</td>
                          <td>Round {{$index}}</td>
                          <td>Blue Corner</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
```

and my script

```
 //Create the module
 var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);



 //Create the controller and register the module in one line
 myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "AngularJS tutorial";
$scope.score = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$scope.rounds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
$scope.selectedRounds = 0;


$scope.tableArray = [];
$scope.getRoundsArray = function() {
     $scope.tableArray = new Array( $scope.selectedRounds * 1);
  }
 });
```

So the amount of rows in the table are dynamically selected and added. Red Corner and Blue Corner will be replaced with drop down lists which have a 1 to 10 value. At the end of the table I will sum the drop down list values so I want to be able to do math on round1Red + round2Red .. and so on. Is there a way I can dynamically assign IDs to each  when the table is created?

Comment: What element do you want to add the id to?

Comment: <td>Red Corner</td> and  <td>Blue Corner</td> will have seperate IDs. Such as redRound[0] and blueRound[0] and so on

Comment: You can set the id based off `$index` variable like so: `id="{{$index}}"`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes thank you. I wasn't aware I could use index in ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add IDs to the table like so:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in tableArray track by $index">
     <td id="redCorner{{$index}}">Red Corner</td>
     <td>Round {{$index}}</td>
     <td id="blueCorner{{$index}}">Blue Corner</td>
 </tr>
```

This should give you unique red and blue corner IDs for each row of the table in the form of `redCorner0, blueCorner0, redCorner1...`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I just came back to re add my solution from your advice. This is more or less what I used. Instead I used
    <td id="{{'redScore'+($index+1)}}">Red Corner</td>

The only difference is the single quotations work inside {{}}. Thanks again

Comment: I also index+1 to start at 1.